# TensorFlow Stopped Working | Update Needed (?)

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, python-import, importerror

Updated to Python 11.0, and Tensorflow stopped working when running

```
import tensorflow
```

on all my programs. I looked for other solutions online and none of them worked. After doing some research, I noticed TF seems to only work for Python 10.0+ apparently? However, shouldn't that mean it should still work, somewhat, with 11.0, or is it not working due to files and compaitibility whatevers. If so, anybody know when they plan on updating it?

When running the aforementioned "import Tensorflow" line, the following errors occur:

The "problems" tab on Visual Studios Code says this:

```
import "tensorflow" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingIMports) [Ln 10, Col 8]
```

And running it on the interactive window shows this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Running the following:

```
pip install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow pip install tensorflow --ignore-installed
```

both result in these errors, by the way:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Anyways, any way to fix this; or any work arounds for this issue while still allowing me to use Python 11.0, or will I just have to use a 10.0 environment for the time being?

Comment: Python 3.11 is not currently supported, you can follow [this article](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/58032) in GitHub for progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to pyreadiness, Tensorflow has not released a build for Python 3.11.
https://pyreadiness.org/3.11/

If you want, you may be able to build Tensorflow from source: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source